# QSEALC/QWAC .NET library for identifying actors in PSD2 API communications

Tags: .net-core, x509, psd2

We are looking to extract additional information from QSEALC/QWAC client certificate in primarily .NET Core code. Optionally in golang or nodejs.

The qualified data (found as an extension to the X509 certificate) is encoded according to ETSI TS 119 495 (https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/119400_119499/119495/01.03.02_60/ts_119495v010302p.pdf), and we were unable to find an open implementation available. We are fine with licensing or cost, as long as the code is inspectable and preferrably open.

Does anyone know of a QSEALC/QWAC .NET library?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional libraries. Because QSEALC and QWAC are just usual X509 certificates.

You'll find a solution in this question: [How do you parse the Subject Alternate Names from an X509Certificate2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698307/how-do-you-parse-the-subject-alternate-names-from-an-x509certificate2)

You just need to use OIDs from the spec you linked.